# How can insert fix value in a field when creating a new row

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on asp.net mvc3. I have designed database in SQL Server. And I access database using ado.net, I am designing a "CREATE" page.

This is my view.cshtml

```
@model CalcoWOMS.Models.ProductFormulation

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "doProductFormulation";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>ProductFormulation</legend>

      <div>  


          @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductID) <!-- i want to insert fix value (100) in this ProductID field in ProductFormulation Table -->
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductID)
    </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RawMaterialID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("RawMaterialID","SELECT")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RawMaterialID)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Code)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Code)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Code)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MinimumBatchSize)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MinimumBatchSize)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MinimumBatchSize)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Quantity)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantity)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Quantity)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "ProductFormulationIndex")
</div>
```

I want to insert fixed value (100) in this `ProductID` field in `ProductFormulation` table and don't want to create editable box. What should I
 do for this ?

Comment: Now how many questions have you asked about mvc in the past few days? Refer some tutorial first. try to work out a solution first

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Also you can use: htmlAttribute where you set: <%= Html.Editor("Testing name","Action",new{ Value="100"}) %> will do that too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I don't understand the question (I'm more of a backend developer), but it seems like the simple solution is remove these two lines:

```
<div>
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductID) 
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductID)
</div>
```

Then update the `Model` in your controller's `Create`, `[post]` method to update the `ProductID` to 100, prior to writing it out to the repository.  Of course, how you'd do that depends on your controller structure, which you haven't posted.

As I understand it, the alternative would be to have a hidden field on the page and create the `Model` with a `ProductID` of 100 in the initial `Create` call but if you're always going to hard code the product id (which to be honest seems questionable) to 100, then this seems pointless...

Comment: sir you right that we should right  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductID)  to allow use to write ProductId, but i want that 100 is stored in Table(model), no need to take input from user ?

Comment: @Pushpendra: There shouldn't be any need to take input from the user, when you already know the value you're planning on writing.  You should be able to just set the value in your controller.

Comment: thank you sir, thank you so much. My problem resolved. Sir may i know your email id so i can ask any question directly. If u dont have any problem in this then please tell me your email id.   my email id is   kuntal.pushpendra@gmail.com

Comment: @Pushpendra Kuntal: That's not really the way `SO` works and to be honest, you're getting better responses on here than you're likely to get if you were to e-mail me *8)